# ViewComponent TagHelpers not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, view-components

There are a few similar questions, but none of which seem to be recent, and Microsoft's documentation doesn't list any special steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The `@await Component.InvokeAsync("TopBooks"...` works without issue, but the `<vc:top-books />` does not render. I added `@addTagHelper *, WebApplication1` to the top of `Index.cshtml` but the TagHelper doesn't work. If you inspect the source it's just written out as is.

I also tried adding `@addTagHelper *, WebApplication1` to `_ViewImports.cshtml` instead with no difference in behaviour.

I created a basic ASP.NET Core Razor Pages .NET 6 application in Visual Studio 2022. `File > New > ASP.NET Core Web App > Next until completed`

I then created a very simple `ViewComponent` and model:

```cs
public class TopBooksViewComponent : ViewComponent {
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(MyBook book) {
        return View(book);
    }
}
```

saved as `Components/TopBooksViewComponent.cs`

```cs
public class MyBook {
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

saved as `Models/MyBook.cs`

Next, I created the View:

```html
@model WebApplication1.Models.MyBook

<h1>Top Books view component</h1>

<p>@Model.Title by @Model.Author</p>
```

saved as `Pages/Shared/Components/TopBooks/Default.cshtml`

Then, to try it out I opened `Pages/Index.cshtml` and modified it to this:

```html
@page
@using WebApplication1.Components
@using WebApplication1.Models
@model IndexModel
@addTagHelper *, WebApplication1

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("TopBooks", new MyBook() {Author = "John Smith", Title = "How to do stuff!"})
    
    <vc:top-books Author="Shepard" Title="The Reapers are coming!"></vc:top-books>
</div>
```

As I said, the `@await Component.InvokeAsync` works with no problem, but the TagHelper does nothing. As far as I can tell there isn't any other special setup required and it comes down to `@addTagHelper *, WebApplication1` not working. However, I am not sure what else I can change it to. `WebApplication1` is the name of my project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 `string` arguments `Author` and  `Title` passed via the taghelper below, don't match the signature of the `Invoke` method.

```
<vc:top-books Author="Shepard" Title="The Reapers are coming!"></vc:top-books>
```

That `Invoke` method expects a `MyBook` instance.

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(MyBook book)
```

The taghelper should pass a `MyBook` object like below.

```
<vc:top-books book="@(new MyBook { Author = "Shepard", Title = "The Reapers are coming!" })"></vc:top-books>
```

Comment: If that isn't a TGIF moment I don't know what is. I definitely should have figured that one out myself. Thanks.

Comment: Well, don't we all need a rubber ducky sometimes? Especially on a Friday.